# Finding a probability from a mgf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I am given the question:
A viral meme starts in one account, and is re-shared by $\mathbf{M}$ other accounts, where $\mathbf{M}$ is a non-negative discrete random variable. Assume that the future
behaviour following from each of the initial re-shares is independent and distributed identically to the sharing behaviour from the initial creation: after $\mathbf{m}$ initial re-shares we
have $\mathbf{m}$ independent and identically distributed copies of the initial meme process. Let $\mathbf{s}$
be the probability that the meme eventually dies out, which is also the probability that any of the $\mathbf{m}$ sub-branches of the process dies out.
We define s as:
$$ s = \sum_{m = 0}^\infty P(M=m)s^m = E(s^M)$$
and using the fact that now M $\sim$ Bin(3,1/2). Calculate $M_{M}(t)$ and hence find plausible values for s.

So I think the $M_{M}t$ is just $(0.5+0.5e^t)^3$ and now to find plausible values of s. I was thinking that using the fact that M is now a Binomial random variable. We can use this to substitue the pmf of M in the sum.As in,
$$ s = \sum_{m = 0}^3 \binom{3}{m} 0.5^m 0.5^{3-m}s^m$$
And this would produce some cubic which we can solve for s.

Comment: I got $$ s = \sum_{m = 0}^3 \binom{3}{m} 0.5^m 0.5^{3-m} s^m$$. The P(M=m) is redundant in my view. The term can be solved by applying the binomial theorem.

Comment: Yh sorry thats what I meant.I will change that. Is this the correct way for solving for s?

Comment: So $s$ on the $left $ side and on the $right$ side are the same?

Comment: Yes they are the same.

Comment: Although it is not clear to me what the goal is. The sum can be simplified to a 3rd degree polynomial with variable $s$. But I suspect that then the goal is to solve for $s$.  I think you are looking for the **Probability Generating Function** (**PGF**).

Comment: The question I am solving is about memes and s is the probability that a meme eventually dies out.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to give some tips anymore. It would be a good idea, if you would post more context, so that it is clear where the equation comes from. Then I'm sure somebody can help. Here is a [link](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Probability_Generating_Function_of_Binomial_Distribution) to the PGF of the binomial distribution. Very familiar.

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks!